# AWS MQTT receive a non pre defined topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I am planning to have a dynamic non predefined topic in AWS IOT. I am just curios is it able to read a topic and perform action from there in example : Let's say if i plug in my thing to network and it's able to subscribe to any topic available, in another word dynamically subscribe to topic? Of course i understand about the required endpoints and credentials but just wondering.

Answer (score 1):

AWS MQTT topics are created dynamically and client subscriptions are dynamic. Clients need to agree on a topic hierarchy/structure apriori in order to communicate.

This is covered by the [MQTT Spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718109) that the AWS IoT broker (partially) implements:

> The topic resource MAY be either predefined in the Server by an administrator or it MAY be dynamically created by the Server when it receives the first subscription or an Application Message with that Topic Name. The Server MAY also use a security component to selectively authorize actions on the topic resource for a given Client.

There are some restrictions with reserved topics starting with `$` and the [policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-policies.html) that authorise access to a topic.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. However how to achieve this in AWSIoTPythonSDK? I have tried basicPubSub example which publishes with a pre-defined topic (and strangely shares the same topic to subscribe).But i couldn't figure out how to read the topic (or where to read it) without pre-defining a topic in thing.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by "read the topic". MQTT is a pub/sub protocol. Topics are created dynamically and messages are published to a topic. If a client wants to receive a message then it subscribes to the topic. Clients need to agree on a topic hierarchy/structure to communicate.

Comment: @Bet T - Thanks Ben for clearing out. I mean if you need to read multi-topics and when the topics is not available to subscribe, how do you identify it.
For example in `myAWSIoTMQTTClient.subscribe(topic...)`, how do you subscribe to multiple topics & if the topic is not available in server, how does this get identified?

Comment: The client needs to know in advance what topic to expect a message on. It can subscribe before a message is published to the topic. This is covered by the "it MAY be dynamically created by the Server when it receives the first subscription" part of the spec. As for subscribing to multiple topics you can just do that. Just call subscribe for each topic.